# Xcode 4 - Using existing projects

Tags: xcode, ios, ios4, xcode4

I have this weird problem which I don't remember to ever had in XCode 3.

I have my head project which I was developing.
Now I want to use another project, but when I drag the .xcodeproj file to my head project from my other project, all it copies is the .xcodeproj file, without nothing else (groups,source files, etc..). 
I remember on Xcode 3 it was asking if to copy or just reference the new project. But now nothing.

Should I do it differently on XCode 4 ?

I even tried to play with a new workspace, but it still behaves the same.

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to add a library project of some sort? And that you actually want to reference it, and not copy it?

Comment: Yes exactly, some Logging framework, and other useful stuff. But I still want the entire secondary to reside in my head project source tree, and for some reason when I drag&drop the .xcodeproj file, it just copies it and that's it. And advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like closing and reopening XCode fixed the issue, it's weird that I have to do it everytime now that I want to reference a new project.
oh well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be treating the .xcodeproj as a resource like an image or other stuff.
I think you'l have to open the other project you want to work with and drag in all the files manually.

Maybe there's a better way, but try doing that for now :)